# Searching a column containing JSON for items in string array

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a SQL column that contains array data such as:

```
["Jimmy","Johnny","Jeffry","Jacob","Justin","Joseph","Josh","Jared"] 
or could be 
["Jimmy","Johnny","Jeffry"].
```

I need to search for names that match all names in the column from a sproc. The query could have 1 or all of these names.

I am currently using OPENJSON to filter on individual names like 'Jimmy' or 'Johnny' but now the requirement is if they choose 'All' I need to bring back the columns that only contain ALL the names, not just 1 name so -

```
["Jimmy","Johnny","Jeffry","Jacob","Justin","Joseph","Josh","Jared"]
 and not 
["Jimmy","Johnny"]
```

so when they select 'All' in the UI I was thinking of having the incoming sql param be a list of all the names (All the ones listed above), comma delimited.

```
 @Names = 'Jimmy,Johnny,Jeffry,Jacob,Justin,Joseph,Josh,Jared'
```

currently to look for an individual item I am doing:

```
 (@Names IN ( SELECT value FROM OPENJSON(a.Names)) OR @Names IS NULL)
```

I believe this requirement may be out of scope for OpenJson but not sure what else to try, maybe a LIKE%?

Any suggestions or questions would be appreciated.

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: @jarlh - SQL Server

Comment: Storing data as json you need to search or filter on is your biggest design flaw, the data should be normalised.

Comment: @Stu, I can agree with that. I didn't create or have control of it, unfortunately.

Comment: Please display your whole code. (@Names IN ( SELECT value FROM OPENJSON(a.Names)) OR @Names IS NULL) won't work for multiple values anyway

Comment: What is your SQL Server version (`SELECT @@VERSION;`)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not pretty but to give the condition that there are no names in the `@Names` array that don't exist in the `Names` column you can do

```
/*Sample Data*/
DECLARE @T TABLE
  (
     Names NVARCHAR(MAX)
  );

INSERT @T
VALUES (N'["Jimmy","Johnny","Jeffry","Jacob","Justin","Joseph","Josh","Jared"]'),
      ( N'["Jimmy","Johnny","Kevin"]')


/*Example @Names value to simulate your parameter*/
DECLARE @Names NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'["Jimmy","Johnny","Jeffry"]';

/*Just parse it once, remove any dupes and use PK so SQL Server can see this*/
DECLARE @NamesToFind TABLE(Name NVARCHAR(100) PRIMARY KEY);

INSERT @NamesToFind (Name)
SELECT DISTINCT value
FROM   OPENJSON(@Names)

/*The actual SELECT*/
SELECT *
FROM   @T T
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT Name
                   FROM   @NamesToFind
                   EXCEPT
                   SELECT value
                   FROM   OPENJSON(T.Names))
```

If `@Names` is null this will match anything as looks desired from the `OR @Names IS NULL` in your current code. And if you want to just match a single name then pass in an array with one element.

This will not be able to do any kind of index seek and will require a full scan of some kind.

Comment: This looks promising. Thank you Martin for the time in adding this. Give me a bit to add it into my stuff and test it.